# Print Preview for Word Doc VB

Tags: vb.net, print-preview

I somewhat inherited a form application that I'm tweaking.. Long story short I merely want a read only view of a word document.  I don't want the overhead of launching Word so I thought maybe just a print style preview.  I somewhat need to stay away from 3rd party apps so I'm limited.  Anyways.. I'm trying to handle pdf's, txt's, image files and word docs.  The problem is that I can't seem to load the print preview.  I can print it.. but no see it in the PrintPreviewController that I added.  Anyone have an example?  I'm trying to be careful w/ overhead because I'm already running 5+ stored procs to retrieve info for this prototype.

Anyone?  My examples are nasty.. but if you want to see I'd be glad to supply..\

Now I gave a shot to using a Webview and it launches rather in the MS Word application itself.. I see documents on registry tweaks needed.. ugh..

Answer (score 0):

I think you may as well use Word. Check your Task Manager Process list - printing the word document will start up an invisible instance of Word anyway.

Comment: hmm.. I'll have to look into that.  I need to find a way to get a mere non editable preview that has as little overhead as possible.  Doesn't even matter if you can only view the first page.

Comment: Maybe you could cache the preview image at document creation? Programmatically take a screenshot of Word and save it somewhere?